# Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

i am using ajax to handle form submission. on form radio button for attribute `status`. now when i try `alert(data)` it alerts [object object].

how can i alert current form submission.

console.log(data)

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

index.html

```
<script>
   $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
     $('.<%= attendance_form_id %>').on('ajax:success', function(event){
      const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail
      $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').hide()
     }).on('ajax:error',function(event){
        alert("Something went wrong, please reload page")
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Try doing a `console.log()` on `event.detail`. See if it is undefined.

Comment: @edddd, ```Uncaught TypeError: event is undefined``` i  error like this. i am able to submit form data, but not able to ```alert``` what data has been submited

Comment: How about `ajaxSuccess` method for do it? `$(...).ajaxSuccess(function(event, xhr, settings ) { your code }`

Comment: @JoonaYoon its working i am able to hide on success ``` $('#<%= attendance_form_id %>').hide()``` also on failure alert is getting executed

Comment: `alert(any_object)` will always display `[object object]` - stop using alert for debugging and use `console.log` instead (or debug using debugging tools)

Comment: @JoonaYoon `ajaxSuccess` will not work with Rails 5.1+.

Comment: @max i am using rails 5.2.4 it's working jquery hide() method is working on success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to rethink your entire approach here. Instead of using an inline script tag (boo) just assign a class to your element and move the script into the assets pipeline/packs. If you think you need to use ERB interpolation to target elements you're just doing it wrong. Stop thinking of your javascript as specific to a single element / page and just design it as behaviors that you can attach to any element by targeting classes and/or attributes.

This is especially important if you are using ES6 features as inline script tags will not be passed through any transpiler if you need legacy browser support.

And instead of wrapping your code in a `turbolinks:load` event handler (boo) and attaching handlers directly to the elements use delegated event handlers:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.my_spiffy_form', function(event){
  const $form = $(this); // this is bound to the element that triggered the event
  const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
  console.log(data, status, xhr);
  // do something ...
}).on('ajax:error', '.my_spiffy_form', function(event){
  const $form = $(this); // this is bound to the element that triggered the event
  const [data, status, xhr] = event.detail;
  console.log(data, status, xhr);
  // do something ...
});
```

This handler is idempotent as it catches the event when it bubbles up to the top of the DOM. The second optional argument to `jQuery.on` is a selector used to filter the elements.

See [Turbolinks: Making Transformations Idempotent](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks#making-transformations-idempotent).

Also note that the arguments passed to the event handler are different depending on which version of Rails you are using:

> Rails 5.1 introduced rails-ujs and dropped jQuery as a dependency.
> [...] Unlike the version with jQuery, all custom events return only
> one parameter: event. In this parameter, there is an additional
> attribute detail which contains an array of extra parameters.
>
> - [Rails Guides: Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#rails-ujs-event-handlers)

The signature of the [old jquery-ujs handler](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) is:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success', '.my_spiffy_form', function(event, data, status, xhr){
  const $form = $(this); // this is bound to the element that triggered the event
  console.log(data, status, xhr);
  // do something ...
})
```

Comment: The only case where you want to use `turbolinks:load` is if you have to integrate some kind of non-idempotent library like all those datepickers and other jquery trinkets.

Comment: i am getting from data as ```undefined```